# vim8 reuse history of commands not working

Tags: vim

In vim7, I can see a history of previous commands with `q:` and if I want to use any of those commands, I can navigate to the particular line and hit `<CR>`. In vim8, hitting `<CR>` does not do anything. Am I missing something?

If I start vim with vim -u NONE and try to view previous commands with `q:`, it doesn't list any commands even though I have just executed one.

Comment: try testing it again with a plain (no extra config, no plugin) vim. your problem cannot be reproduced here.

Comment: @Kent: see updated question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was a bug in Vim which has been fixed with patch 8.0.0208